# How to style scrollbars on ExtJs layout?

Tags: jquery, css, extjs, extjs4

I have some panels on an `AccordionLayout` where I need to style the scrollbars.

Pure CSS is not a solution, since I need cross-browser styles, and any Javascript solution (tried [Antiscroll](http://t.co/Llay6TI5CM) and [Perfect Scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.com/perfect-scrollbar/)) seens to work…

ExtJs resizes the containers to let space enough to scrollbars, so qhen the plugins mentioned above hides the scrollbar, its space is still present, like an ugly border.

The best solution would be an ExtJs implementation of scrollbars. But I can't find anyone.

[Screenshot of the Accordion Menu](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s93/sh/bed3f285-207e-45a5-a8c2-fe606143415c/d212b3a341b54feb01bc89829fc8c587)

Comment: Right-click, inspect element, write your own CSS override.

Comment: It doesn't work. ExtJs adjust the `width` of any component children. I added a screenshot of the problema.

Comment: I don't know what you used but you should trigger an event to call `update` function of the `perfect-scrollbar`.